# Task is called twice in Spring MVC 4.0

Tags: spring

I am using Spring MVC 4.0 with Hibernate 4.0.1. I set @Scheduled(cron="0 21,22 17 * * *",The task is called twice by every time.If i run stand alone application , task is called one time, but if i call it from Web Container, taks is called two times. 
If I remove org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from web.xml, Web Application is not loading.HTTP Status 500 - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

```
<bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay" class="com.mysource.batch.DemoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay"></bean> 
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

Solution:

What is probably happening is that the bean that is annotated with @Scheduled is being included in both the root application context and the web application context.

```
        I separated @Scheduled related bean and prepared separate xml.THis xml is loaded from web.xml.

        Servlet-context.xml
        ----------------------
            <bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay" class="com.bics.batch.DemoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay"></bean>
            <task:scheduled-tasks>
                <task:scheduled ref="demoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay" method="demoServiceMethod" cron="0 35,36 12 * * *"></task:scheduled>
            </task:scheduled-tasks>
        Web.xml:
        -------
         <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
                         /WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml,
                         /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param> 

        Now Task is called one time and more over i am able to run web application also.
```

Comment: If it run twice the bean is instantiated twice. Don't load the same beans in both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: What is probably happening is that the bean that is annotated with `@Scheduled` is being included in both the root application context and the web application context. Please show your Spring configuration so we can help further

Comment: <bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay" class="com.bics.batch.DemoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay"></bean> 
 <task:annotation-driven/> 
  If I remove ContextLoaderListener from web.xml, i couldn't run web application.

Comment: Hi Geoand, Please find my spring configuration file.

Comment: <bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay" class="com.bics.batch.DemoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay"></bean> 
 <task:annotation-driven/>

Comment: HI Geoand, any update for this issue?